$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(4^{x}-1)^{3}}{\sin(\frac{x}{4})\ln(1+\frac{x^{2}}{3})}$
Compute
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(4^{x}-1)^{3}}{\sin(\frac{x}{4})\ln(1+\frac{x^{2}}{3})}$$
My try
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(4^{x}-1)^{3}}{\frac{\frac{x}{4}(sin\frac{x}{4})}{\frac{x}{4}}(\frac{(1+\frac{x^{2}}{3})ln(1+\frac{x^{2}}{3})}{(1+\frac{x^{2}}{3})})}$$
Now we can seperate those standard limits of ln and sin function
And now use the following expansion
$$4^x-1=x\ln4+\frac{x^2(\ln4)^2}{2}+\cdots$$
And cancelling factors gives that $x^2$ term at the top thus it's limit should be 0 but the answer is given to be $12(\ln4)^3$

Hint: Use the following well-known limits for $x \to 0$:
a) $\dfrac{4^x - 1}{x} \to \ln 4$
b) $\dfrac{\sin(\frac{x}{4})}{\frac{x}{4}} \to 1$
c) $\dfrac{\ln(1+\frac{x^2}{3})}{\frac{x^2}{3}}\to 1$.
Can you put it together to finish it?

Yeah I saw this answer somewhere else ,but can you please help me find my mistake.

@AnshuGupta: The $1$ at the denominator is the trouble. It shouldn't be there and only the $\dfrac{x^2}{3}$ there only.

To be honest this answer needs a bit more elaboration. OP: your work is not clear, you handwave your last line or two.

I got my mistake Actually it's a silly mistake I should have thought a bit more before asking Im sorry I got it @WangYeFei should I delete my question now or leave it?

@AnshuGupta: I would leave it as is because you can learn from your mistake and later you can go back and see how much progress you've made. No harm to leave it here.

The Taylor series expansion of $(4^x-1)^3$ around $x=0$ is $(x \ln 4 +O(x^2))^3 = x^3 \ln^3 4 + O(x^4)$.
The Taylor series expansion of $\sin \Big(\frac{x}{4}\Big)$ around $x=0$
is $\frac{x}{4}+O(x^2)$.
The Taylor series expansion of $\ln\Big(1+\frac{x^2}{3}\Big)$ around $x=0$ is $\frac{x^2}{3}+O(x^3)$.
Using this:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^3 \ln^3 4 +O(x^4)}{\Big(\frac{x}{4}+O(x^2)\Big)\Big(\frac{x^2}{3}+O(x^3)\Big)} \ = \  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^3 \ln^3 4}{\Big(\frac{x}{4}\Big)\Big(\frac{x^2}{3}\Big)}$$
$$= \ 12 \ln^3 4.$$
